# HasFilter() is not working for PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have this configuration for my entity:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserGroup> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasIndex(group => group.ExternalId)
                .HasFilter("\"ExternalId\" IS NOT NULL")
                .IsUnique();
        }
```

But it still selects records where `ExternalId` is `null`, how to fix it?

Comment: "it still selects" what does that have to do with the index definition? It's not a `CHECK` constraint, just a filtered index. If you don't want `ExternalId` to ever be null then define it as not nullable in your model.

Comment: As said, it defines a filter on the index, which does not determine what a query returns. Did you mean to define a [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)?